# Filter interface by array of keys

Tags: typescript

Imagine you have an interface:

```js
interface Human {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number;
}
```

and you have a function that takes an array of its keys. I want the returned value to be an object with only those keys.

```js
const human: Human = {
   name: 'test';
   age: 101;
   height: 104;
}
const getPartialHuman = (keys: keyof Human[]) => {
   return Object.keys(human).reduce((acc, val) => {
       if keys.includes(val) {
          acc[val] = human[val]l
       }
       return acc;
   }, {});
}
const partialHuman = getPartialHuman(['name', 'age']);

partialHuman.name; // should be ok
partialHuman.age; // should be ok
partialHuman.height; // ERROR: does not exist on type
```

I would like the type to be able to infer the valid properties based on the input array.

I believe it should be possible, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Something like:

```js
const getPartialHuman = <T extends keyof Human>(keys: keyof T[]): Pick<Human, T> => {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proposed type signature for `getPartialHuman` is essentially correct. I think your problem is that your use of `keyof` is erroneous. `keyof T[]` does not mean `(keyof T)[]`; `keyof T[]` means `keyof (T[])` i.e. 'the keys of `T[]`', and `T[]` is an array, so its keys are `number`s.

Here's a working writeup of the code as you wrote it ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcC2cTIN4BQyxyIcmEAXMgM5hSgDmA3ESXI1aVgEbSslkACwjBGQsNRC9+BAL4ECCAPYg6wrDmoZsuALz42pclwDkkOqYA0RjlwCMABns2SIsROpOALDYVLVdU4wAAU4KDBgOAAbHRxkAwAeABVkCAAPSBAAExpkAGsIAE9lGDRNEAA+AApCoppqZIBtAF0ASmoQ4AR8xLiQK2RkyoSRwhIoCDB0KFwAeR4AKwgEMAA6OppqoQq2tcns9CRq6sQETvDImL6KysGANxi20cNBEmAy2uKaNdAEaPQ2QgW0e0WQcDyyTaz3Gb0EZyaoPBkJaCQ0ukRMWRQxaAjhCjhyEm01m4IQCDxyDkgzwcmeEOQXR6N10g2GrH8KjUYGQAAdLlFYhU0cEwhFBf1qk0AERkCjSwbSuzS9rIAD0asZ3V6-UVcog0uQAB9kErONLKkA)):

```
interface Human {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number;
}

const human: Human = {
   name: 'test',
   age: 101,
   height: 104,
}

const getPartialHuman = <T extends keyof Human>(keys: T[]): Pick<Human, T> => {
   return Object.keys(human).reduce((acc: Partial<Human>, val) => {
       if (keys.includes(val as T)) {
          acc[val as T] = human[val as T];
       }
       return acc;
   }, {}) as Pick<Human, T>;
}

const partialHuman = getPartialHuman(["name", "age"]) // Pick<Human, "name" | "age">
```

This is a bit awkward, though. Here's how I'd probably rewrite it ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcC2cTIN4BQyxyIcmEAXMgM5hSgDmA3ESXI1aVgEbSslkACwjBGQsNRC9+BAL4ECCAPYg6wrDmoZsuALz42pclwDkkOqYA0RjlwCMABns2SIsROpOALDYVLVdU4wAAU4KDBgOAAbHRxkAwAeABVkCAAPSBAAExpkAGsIAE9lGDRNEAA+AApCoppqZIBtAF0ASmoQ4AR8xLiQK2RkyoSRwhIoCDB0KFwAeR4AKwgEMAA6GChlTABRcAYIGlrimjXsAAdq46K20eQmusGhCofilvbbuDyunr6KweG8kUKjUYGQ53CkRi-QSyGCYQiUViFWqTQARGQKGjBmi7Gj2sgAPSE5A-Xr9HGYiBo5AAH2QuM4aMqQA)):

```
const getPartialHuman = <T extends keyof Human>(keys: T[]): Pick<Human, T> => {
   return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, human[key]])) as Pick<Human, T>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following class:

```
class Car {
  public constructor(
    public wheels: number,
    public doors: number,
    public size: string
  ) {}

  getCarProperties<T extends keyof Car>(...keys: T[]): Pick<Car, T> {
    const selectedProperties: Pick<Car, T> = {} as Pick<Car, T>;

    keys.forEach((key) => {
      selectedProperties[key] = car[key];
    });

    return selectedProperties;
  }
}
```

Then we initialize a Car class:

```
const car: Car = new Car(2, 4, 'medium');
console.log(car); // { wheels: 2, doors: 4, size: 'medium' }
```

Then we call the method which takes only properties as input and outputs
the created 'partial':

```
const subCar = car.getCarProperties('wheels', 'doors');
console.log(subCar); // { wheels: 4, doors: 2 }
```

[Runnable code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8BQ1oAcCuAjEAlsNMAPYB2EALgtsFaQgBToZZ6HEDuAFgKZ8QEAFzRy2ALa4+CADSsMOfEWgATUoxFjJ0uQvbLiEAgC8+o6ggLkA5qwCUKAL6pWNvlXgIACglKYZKgI+CAAeABVoPgAPKj5yVRgAaz4AT1IAMzhEAD4mADpClNStcIBtAF17UW8iJNCvWWhwnJR9MkoqaAhBPno+VV9-QOCtWuB6xubWgF5naEhoccnEJpaAblc2aGKIfIzGAFEwYB4mJmLHGda0bYwekD64wb8AhCCQsuKK6DngRC+aQqm22Tnsm30CA82AQ5G6vX6L2G71GIOgLhcqA61BIiFEXl+Yj4XGyzAATE0ACxNADkEgGBEkNPBWIoEFIj3yIFINiY-wQ4OgAHohShoLwBEJRBS1BoEFpqd1TOZoHSGUz0a5sV0IHgCX9EPl3J5EEM3h8IEwaRLBBAabT1JpmZtsRy+FyeUxdbgvIKRWKbVLoIrHfLpeigA)

**explanation**

> have a function that takes an array of its keys

The trick here is this line:

```
getCarProperties<T extends keyof Car>(...keys: T[])
```

You define T that should be the keyof Car, which you have done so correctly. In my case I take the keys in as arguments rather than array to make the method a bit more userfriendly.

> I want the returned value to be an object with only those keys.

After fetching the keys, I just define a new object and assign the specific properties from its parent to the new object.
The type of that new object should be something like: `Pick<Car, T>`

Hope it helps!

**Edit**:
One thing I forgot to emphasize is that the types themselves already verify whether the keys are correct or not as it should do. Your IDE will complain if it is not a property of Car.

However, in the case that you have something like a DTO or acquire these keys from other user input, then you could add a check like: `if (car.hasOwnProperty(key))` in the foreach loop.